# Matchmaking with Facebook Graph API 2.0: how to create an unique room name which both players know?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, multiplayer

I'd like to figure out what's the best way to create an unique room name in a one-vs-one multiplayer game? The idea was to combine user's and his friend's ids. However, in Graph API 2.0, an app cannot retrieve friend's real id, and even cannot retrieve friend's app-specific id if the friend is not a user of this app. With real ids, it was possible to generate unique room name which both clients know without additional communication. Any way to do that in Graph API 2.0? I can combine user's and his friend's names, but there's no guarantee that this room name will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand: How can they both play a game together, if the second user is not using the app? If he's using the app, you should be able to retrieve his app-scoped id.

Apart from that, there are many way to generate hashes that will not have collisions, meaning that you can generate a random hash and use this as unique id.

Comment: Say, I'd like to play with my friend. In the app, I just click "Challenge friend", choose a friend from a list of all friends and the room is created. My Friend got an invitation to play with me, he first authorizes the app, then, after clicking "Challenge friend" and choosing my name from a list he joins my room. I'm trying to avoid sending invitation to the app and then sending invitation to the room, I'd like to use only one invitation for that.

Comment: Makes sense... I'd think about using a hash as unique id, as I suggested. The implementation depends on the programming language you're using though.